# How to insert React state value into HTML Template with predefined value in Sun Editor?

Tags: reactjs, suneditor

I have some user insert fields like title, date, time, and also a select dropdown option with some values. Below these fields, there is a text editing option using [suneditor react](https://www.npmjs.com/package/suneditor-react), so when I click the select dropdown then automatically an HTML template with predefined value is inserted into this text editing filed.

Now I want to replace the predefined values of text editing field with user inserted date, time etc. Any resource, video, blog or advice?

FAQ: this is an invitation template integrated with mail config, where a dropdown list item is selected then predefined data are inserted into text editing field of sun editor, now need to change some value from user inserted input field.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are probably looking for this:

**setContents(contents)**

```
Change the contents of the suneditor
Parameters:
Name      Type    Description
contents  String  Contents to Input

Where contents can be a state string...
```

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const [content, setContent] = useState("<span>Hello monster dev!!!</span>");
<SunEditor
      name="content"
      setContents={content}// <=
      placeholder="Dev Monster"
      defaultValue={content}
      onChange={text => setContent(text)}
    ...
/>
```

Ref: http://suneditor.com/sample/html/out/document-user.html